# Can't open Android Studio - 2021.1.1.23-windows

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I just installed Android Studio (version 2021.1.1.23-windows), but when i execute studio.exe (or studio.bat) to open Android Studio, it just won't open.

This is the log when i run studio.bat in the command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\AndroidStudio\bin>studio.bat
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.InvocationUtil to field java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.runnable
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.InvocationUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2022-04-17 19:32:00,645 [    124]   WARN -        #com.intellij.idea.Main - Unable to load JNA library (OS: Windows 10 10.0)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Gonalo Martins\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.1\tmp\jna7091873651992604468.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2430)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2487)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2684)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2617)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:765)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1835)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:1019)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:989)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:195)
        at com.intellij.jna.JnaLoader.load(JnaLoader.java:18)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.loadSystemLibraries(StartupUtil.java:655)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$prepareApp$4(StartupUtil.java:235)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:216)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:27)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:195)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:187)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2022-04-17 19:32:01,489 [    968]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator)
2022-04-17 19:32:01,568 [   1047]   WARN - tor.impl.FontFamilyServiceImpl - Couldn't access required runtime API, will fall back to basic logic of font selection
2022-04-17 19:32:01,884 [   1363]   WARN - tellij.ide.SystemHealthMonitor - issue detected: bundled.jre.version.message
2022-04-17 19:32:04,486 [   3965]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg$HKEYByReference.<init>(WinReg.java:52)
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg$HKEYByReference.<init>(WinReg.java:48)
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util.registryGetKeys(Advapi32Util.java:2028)
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util.registryGetKeys(Advapi32Util.java:2012)
        at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.CpuVendor.getCpuVendor(CpuVendor.kt:30)
        at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.CpuVendor.isIntel(CpuVendor.kt:38)
        at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.Haxm.<clinit>(Haxm.kt:91)
        at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.deprecated.InstallComponentsPath.createComponentTree(InstallComponentsPath.java:138)
        at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.deprecated.InstallComponentsPath.init(InstallComponentsPath.java:204)
        at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:98)
        at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:233)
        at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.deprecated.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:90)
        at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.deprecated.FirstRunWizardHost.lambda$setupWizard$0(FirstRunWizardHost.java:121)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:421)
        at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.deprecated.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:119)
        at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.deprecated.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:112)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.<init>(WelcomeFrame.java:64)
        at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizardFrameProvider.lambda$createFrame$0(FirstRunWizardFrameProvider.java:42)
        at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionProcessingHelper.computeSafeIfAny(ExtensionProcessingHelper.java:56)
        at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.ExtensionPointName.computeSafeIfAny(ExtensionPointName.java:54)
        at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizardFrameProvider.createFrame(FirstRunWizardFrameProvider.java:38)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.lambda$prepareToShow$1(WelcomeFrame.java:172)
        at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionProcessingHelper.computeSafeIfAny(ExtensionProcessingHelper.java:56)
        at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.ExtensionPointName.computeSafeIfAny(ExtensionPointName.java:54)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.lambda$prepareToShow$2(WelcomeFrame.java:172)
        at com.intellij.idea.IdeStarter$showWizardAndWelcomeFrame$1.run(IdeStarter.kt:173)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:218)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$200(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:200)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:787)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$invokeLater$4(ApplicationImpl.java:325)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:84)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:133)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:46)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue$FlushNow.run(FlushQueue.java:189)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:969)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:839)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:808)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:448)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:787)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:496)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
2022-04-17 19:32:04,500 [   3979]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3  Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675
2022-04-17 19:32:04,503 [   3982]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - JDK: 11.0.13; VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation
2022-04-17 19:32:04,503 [   3982]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - OS: Windows 10
2022-04-17 19:32:04,505 [   3984]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - Last Action:
```

And then stops and don' inicialize.

To run studio.bat i use *Java SE Development Kit 11.0.13* (Java SE 11)

Comment: IDE fails to load native libraries, probably because of the security restrictions. Please ask your admins to allow IDE process to do it (IDE may use idea.system.path for that, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519).